# facebook API error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an html/js/php app that posts to a page feed (the page is attached to an application).
 With chrome everything works perfectly but with IE in windows and Safari on Mac I get the following error:

```
error: Object
code: 200
message: "(#200) The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories"
type: "OAuthException"
```

js code: http://pastebin.com/20D8iGG8 
login code: http://pastebin.com/U0y04MA0

The user has the correct permissions of course.

edit:

Fiddling around i found out that it wasn't a browser problem but it's an account problem, from one account it works and from the other one it doesn't, i have to find out which settings are causing this.

I double checked the security settings of the auth dialog and the scope on the login and everything seems to be in order, so it's still very weird.

Comment: This id odd. Please post relevant code.

Comment: this is the js code: http://pastebin.com/20D8iGG8

Comment: Where’s your actual login, where you request the necessary permission from the user?

Comment: this is the login code: http://pastebin.com/U0y04MA0

Comment: just edited with my latest findings, this is getting strange

Comment: Since it works for one account but not another, is one account different than the other, maybey a developer or administrator of the app?

Comment: yes, the one where it doesn't work is the account from which i created the app and the community page!